# Inno Setup: How do I update a progress bar using the Inno Download Plugin

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

I was previously using the [DwinsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php) plugin for downloading files in the internet.
Now I am trying to move to the [Inno Download Plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inno-download-plugin/).

In my installer I create my own progress bar using `TNewProgressBar.Create(WizardForm);`.
I need to update this progress bar when I download a file from the internet using the [Inno Download Plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inno-download-plugin/).

In [DwinsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php) I would use the function [DwinsHs_ReadRemoteURL](http://www.han-soft.com/releases/dwinshs/documents/f_readremoteurl.html) to download files from the internet and update my progress bar while downloading.

This function would also have a very convenient fallback `OnRead`, which I used to update my progress bar while downloading the file from the internet.

Is it possible to download a file from the internet using [Inno Download Plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/inno-download-plugin/) and update my progress bar while downloading?

Answer (score 1):

The Inno Download plugin creates its own progress page by default, when you call the `idpDownloadAfter` function.

See any of theirs examples. Picking the `examples\example1.iss`:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test1.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test1.zip'));
    idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test2.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test2.zip'));
    idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test3.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test3.zip'));

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

---

If you want to bind your own progress bar (or other controls) to the Inno Download plugin backend, see what `idpConnectControls` function in the `idp.iss` does:

```pascal
idpConnectControl('TotalProgressBar',   IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Handle);
idpConnectControl('FileProgressBar',    IDPForm.FileProgressBar.Handle);
```